# SWRevealViewController: animate a nav bar icon when triggering a reveal

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

This question references the excellent SWRevealViewController library.

I have a simple implementation of a homeVC (front) and a menuVC (rear). Both VCs are imbedded in navigation controllers. I use a standard "hamburger" UIBarButtonItem to trigger the reveal segue from homeVC to menuVC. All is working happily.

My question is: I would like to trigger a transformation where the hamburger changes from the standard icon (state 0), to something else (state 1). I would like to implement this so that the transformation is tied to the degree to which the reveal segue is complete.

I don't want a cut and paste answer. I'd prefer some ideas how this could be accomplished theoretically?

Answer (score 0):

I had this question also & edited the source of swrevealviewcontroller to complete this action. But after that also you can only detect when the user Tap the UIBarButtonItem. If the user swipe to show the RearView then it's not possible to detect. I think that's a disadvantage of swrevealviewcontroller as well